Functions marked 'async' must have a return type which is a supertype of 'Future'
I have this function but its doesn't work because async keyword must add a Future return type, and I can't add Future because I need the value to create a stream for StreamBuilder.
Iterable<Object>? followingUser(String uid)  async {
  final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  try {
    final userSnapshot = await firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get();

    if (userSnapshot.exists) {
      final followedUsers = List<String>.from(userSnapshot['following']);

      final posts = await firestore
          .collection('posts')
          .where('uid', whereIn: followedUsers)
          .get();
      print('this is following users');
      print(followedUsers);
      return followedUsers;
    } else {
      print('User not found.');
      return null;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error retrieving posts: $e');
  }

StreamBuilder:
final followingUsers = firestoreMethods.followingUser(uid);
...
...
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('posts')
            .where(
              'uid',whereIn: followingUsers
            )
            .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
builder:.....
),
),

When I remove async keyword:

The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'

When I add a Future return type to the function, I got this error:

The argument type 'Future<Iterable?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Object?>?'


Your issue is that FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(...).where can't accept a Future for is whereIn argument.  It has nothing to do with StreamBuilder.  Your followingUser function must return a Future.  Since you need the completed value of that Future before you can use FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(...).where, you must wait for that Future to complete first (possibly by using an outer FutureBuilder before you try to build your StreamBuilder.

Also, it seems weird that you're using a StreamBuilder with FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(...).where that is used with an argument that also internally calls FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(...).where.  Is that really what you want?  It seems to me that what you actually want is to make your followingUser function return a Stream that you pass directly to the StreamBuilder.  If so, followingUser should be declared with async*, return a Stream<Object?>, and yield the elements of the Stream.  See https://dart.dev/libraries/async/creating-streams
